# Missing Jar files for Si4T/Solr compile (cd_datalayer)

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, si4t, solr

I am currently trying to compile `si4t` storage extension, I have cloned from the Github repo and it seems I am missing a few jar files when I build. I am currently working on a project using the following versions:

SDL Web Content Manager : 8.6.0
SDL Web Content Manager Explorer: 8.6.0.45274
SDL Web Experience Manager:  8.6.0.46292

I've checked that the pom.xml file has the correct references and versions but the `cd_datalayer`jar appears to be no longer available in the maven repo.

[image: Missing cd_datalayer jar in maven]

The full error is below:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project si4t-se: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.si4t:si4t-se:jar:1.3: Failed to collect dependencies at com.tridion:cd_datalayer:jar:[8.5.0,8.5.1): No versions available for com.tridion:cd_datalayer:jar:[8.5.0,8.5.1) within specified range
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of documents or locations of this jar files?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps to fix your issue.

1. Go to SDL Tridion Sites 8.5 Installation Media folder
2. Navigate to this path: \Content Delivery\roles\deployer\deployer-combined\standalone\services\deployer-common\ and copy the file c**d_datalayer-8.5.0-1014.jar** to your local path folder for example c:\temp
3. Open cmd as administrator and go to c:\temp and run the below command to Installing Tridion libraries into the local Maven repository...

> call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tridion
>   -DartifactId=cd_datalayer -Dversion=8.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=cd_datalayer-8.5.0-1014.jar

4. And then try to build your source it will work.

I hope it will help to resolve your issue.